# FIFA 14 Pro Career

Tags: fifa-14

I love FIFA (XBOX 360), especially Pro Career Mode, and I just came back  from a loan, and I've been playing with the same Mexican team for over 5 seasons, and my player's average is 86. I've requested a transfer so many times, and I never get a single transfer offer. I cannot find a solution to this. Do you now what can be the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Your problem might be that your manager never accepted your transfer request